# Ajax request returns POST <<url>> 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've been doing this module for a website using WAMP Server and everything works, but when I upladed it to the website server it always returns Error 500.

[Error 500 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fPpYt.png)

[Error 500 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Zjuq.png)

When the main page index.php loads (using Javascript .ready function) it send an ajax request to 'obtenermunicipio.php'.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '../obtenermunicipio.php',
          data : {'valor':'paz'},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data) {
            if(data.length <= 0) {
              return;
            }
            for(var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var opcion = document.createElement('option');
                opcion.innerHTML+=data[i];
                document.getElementById('unidadmedica').appendChild(opcion);
            }
          },
          error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
          }
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

The page 'obtenermunicipio.php' receive the value 'valor' and made an MySQL query to obtain an array data that it's return.

```
<?php
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/Noticias/conexion.php');
    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');
    header("application/json");
    $conexion=conectar();
    $municipio = utf8_decode($_POST['valor']);
    if($municipio != "loret")
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT unidadmedica FROM `unidadesmedicas` WHERE municipio like '%".$municipio."%' AND localidad NOT LIKE '%loret%'";
    else
        $sql = "SELECT DISTINCT unidadmedica FROM `unidadesmedicas` WHERE localidad like '%".$municipio."%'";
    $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error($conexion)); 
    $fila = mysql_fetch_all($rs);
    print json_encode($fila);
?>
```

any ideas of how to solve it? it works fine on Wamp.

Comment: probably a php error, check the error log on the server

Comment: Check your server error logs

Comment: It's a Linux server, what's the name of the log file?

Comment: quite possibly `mysql_` functions are not supported, you should use mysqli in any case.

Comment: If you can't find the error logs file, you can just `error_reporting(-1); ini_set("display_errors", true);` and have the error printed.
Also, like @inarilo said, use mysqli or PDO instead. If the PHP version you're running is above 5.4 you'll get E_DEPRECATED notices and if you're running PHP7 they'll turn into fatal errors.

Comment: Uncaught ReferenceError: error_reporting is not defined
    at Object.error (index.php:28)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4)

Comment: mysqli_ are not supported actually. The server only supports mysql_

Comment: You need to do that in PHP, error 500 means something is wrong on the server

Comment: Ok, i found the file and it says:

Comment: [Mon Sep 11 15:59:02 2017] [error] [client 201.147.242.125] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_all() in /var/www/html/obtenermunicipio.php on line 11, referer: http://saludbcs.gob.mx/APLICACIONMOVIL/index.php

Comment: I don't think the mysql_fetch_all function exists. Are you sure you didn't read about mysqli_fetch_all instead?

Comment: Yes, my mistake, i thought it was the same in the old mysql extension, is there any function to replace it?

Comment: It is weird, because I replace the function with $rs = mysql_query($conexion, $sql) or die(mysql_error($conexion)); 
   $fila = array();

   while($row = $rs->fetch_assoc()) {
    $fila[] = $row;
   } and the error_log still says [Tue Sep 12 08:17:02 2017] [error] [client 201.147.242.125] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mysql_fetch_all() in /var/www/html/obtenermunicipio.php on line 11, referer: --------------------- It is saved and everything.

Comment: Well forget it, sublime was not saving the file correctly, I save it with text edit and now it is giving the next error: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /var/www/html/obtenermunicipio.php on line 14, referer:----------------

Answer (score 1):

I'm putting this inside a reply instead of a comment because I feel like they were getting hard to keep track of since there are multiple things to say.

Error 500 means that there's something wrong with your PHP script that could not be handled correctly by the web server. It's usually something like an undeclared (or deprecated) function or some issue with paths or extensions.

The first step to follow in order to investigate the issue is either finding the error_log file on your web server, or pasting these two lines at the top of your php script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1); // highest error reporting level
ini_set("display_errors", true); // print errors directly as output
/* all the rest here */
```

That said, there is one more issue with your code! Be aware that it's really vulnerable against SQL Injection attacks since you're building the query string directly and someone else might have your query do something totally different.

To solve that, you should either use PDO and MySQLi extensions' prepared statements or pass all the variables you're going to use in your query string through `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: Like a post before, the error_reporting() function doesn't works, it always returns: Uncaught ReferenceError: error_reporting is not defined
    at Object.error (index.php:28)
    at i (jquery.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as rejectWith] (jquery.min.js:2)
    at A (jquery.min.js:4)
    at XMLHttpRequest.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:4). I will take into consideration the mysql_real_escape_string(), because the server can't handle MySQLi or PDO extension'